# Loop through each cell in a column, compare each cell to a list and enter an associated description into an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Objective: loop through a column of Numbers/Codes and match these Codes to their descriptions (in a list) and populate the cell in the next column with the associated description.  For example: A2=123456, A3=885467, A4=954789 and so on...  Read in the first cell, A2 (123456). Find 123456 in the list (123456 = Finance), place "Finance" in B2.  Read in 885467 (A3). Find (885467 = Marketing) in the list, place "Marketing" in B3...  and so on.  The closest I've come to solving this is:

```
Sub JobCodeDescription()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'There are 3 worksheets in this Workbook.
            'Job Code
            'Location Code
            'Entity Code
        'Dim x As Number
        Dim f As Range
        For Each f In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("F").Cells
            If f = "00053" Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Finance"
            ElseIf f = "00056" Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Marketing"
            ElseIf f = "00082" Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Technology"
            ' continues on...
        Next f
        ' This works but the Active Cell DOES NOT move with "f". So the same cell continues to be populated and overwritten.
    Next ws
End Sub
```

These Codes never come to me in any specific order and there WILL be duplicates, so I've tried sorting in ascending order. That seems to help, but I just can't figure out the looping through the Job Codes, and looping through the list to find the matching Code description.  I might be going about this all wrong.  I'd like to just compare the codes in column A to a flat-file but I don't know how to do that.  The "Flat-File" is just a .txt file and it is a list of the Job Codes and their descriptions.  Example: 123456 = Finance.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From your description, could you instead use a `Vlookup()` or `Index/Match`? Could you post a sample table, and sample expected output? It sounds like this could be done with formulas, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You need to change `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value` to `f.Offset(0, 1).Value`.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the first 3 rows the worksheet and the flat-file?

Comment: Are the Job Codes stored as text?

Comment: Here is a copy of the WrkSheet.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, if I understand it correctly, I think you'd be better off with `Vlookup()`, since it's a built-in function and doesn't require macros.

If your data table is in `J1:K4`, and your list of accounts is in `A1:A4`, you can use the following formula in `B1`, and copy down:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,$J$1:$K$4,2,FALSE)`

This will search the range `J1:J4` for the value in `A1`, then return the matching value in column `K`:

[image]

But, if you want to use your macro, @ThomasInzina is correct, you need to use `f.Offset(...)` instead of `ActiveCell.Offset(...)`.

Comment: Yall Rock!!!   @Bruce, & Thomas.  Both of those solutions worked!  I first used the VLOOKUP option in order to get the file out in time...  I am now working on creating a macro using the f.Offset() option.  Thank you again!!